# Linq To XML: Writing xsi into an element?

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

Just playing about with LinqToXml and I need to form a xelement as follows:

```
    Dim xe As XElement = _
    <Xml>
        <ElementOne>
            <SubElement></SubElement>
            <SubElement></SubElement>
        </ElementOne>
        <ElementWithXsi xsi:type="XsiForElementWith">
            <SubElement></SubElement>
        </ElementWithXsi>
    </Xml>
```

This creates an error here: xsi:type "XML namespace prefix 'xsi' is not defined"

Is it possible to write this in Linq to xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well with XML and namespaces any prefix besides the "xml" and the "xmlns" prefixes needs to be defined so you need `xmlns:xsi="someURI"` (probably `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` but that is a guess, I don't know which namespace you want) in your XML document or, as long as you use VB.NET's XML literals you can use `Imports <xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">` in program's Imports section.